# Move all lines until a blank line is found

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to move all lines from `String apa1;` to `String apa2;` until we find the first blank line.

---

**apa1 can look like this:**

```
texttest: text test
test text test text

Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet, consectetur 
adipiscing: elit. 
Curabitur dolor lectus, 
cursus ac placerat vitae, 
volutpat sit: amet lacus.
```

---

**I want apa1 to look like this:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet, consectetur 
adipiscing: elit. 
Curabitur dolor lectus, 
cursus ac placerat vitae, 
volutpat sit: amet lacus.
```

---

**And apa2 to look like this:**

```
texttest: text test
test text test text
```

How do you solve this problem?

Comment: What have you tried?  Show us your code, and describe the difficulties you've encountered.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this. Just keep copying the first string to the second string until you hit a blank line

```
String apa1 = @"texttest: text test
                test text test text

                Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet, consectetur 
                adipiscing: elit. 
                Curabitur dolor lectus, 
                cursus ac placerat vitae, 
                volutpat sit: amet lacus.";
String apa2 = string.Empty;

String tmp = String.Copy(apa1);
StringReader strReader = new StringReader(tmp );
String line = strReader.ReadLine();

while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
{
    apa2 += line;
    line = strReader.ReadLine();
}

apa1 = strReader.ReadToEnd();
```